# Как реализовать Bottom Sheet внутри фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Я хочу реализовать Bottom Sheet внутри фрагмента, но Android Studio не видит в методе OnCreate() метод getSupportFragmentManager()

> фрагмент в котором надо реализовать Bottom Sheet

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AimsFragment extends Fragment {


    public AimsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button showModalBottomSheet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aim_dialog_modal);
        showModalBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Initializing a bottom sheet
                BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new AimsBottomSheetDialogFragment();

                //show it
                bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aims, container, false);

    }

}
```

> XML фрагмента Bottom Sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mederov.timelord.AimsFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/as_modal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/logo_splash_margin_endorright"
            android:text="@string/author" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Код который реализует Bottom Sheet

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.view.View;
public class AimsBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.aims_dialog_modal, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

> XML выдвигающегося Bottom Sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Download"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/scheldule"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Upload"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/author" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите найти метод который пренадлежит не `fragment` а `activity`. Если вы вызываете `getSupportFragmentManager()` в фрагменте то должны указкать `activity`. Пример:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Согласно документации данный метод пренадлежит класу `FragmentActivity`, по этой причине ваша `activity` которая выступает контейнером для `fragment` должна быть унаследована от этого класа. Так же стоит сказать что данный метод был отмечен как `deprecated` в версиях 28 и выше. Взамен рекомендуеться использовать такое выражение:

```
FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```